# firefox webdriver for selenium on debian issue

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, installation, debian

How do I install the webdriver.Firefox() on debian?

When I execute my python script, for now I get this error:

> untimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please
>   specify the firefox binary location or install firefox

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Comment: Where is firefox installed?

Comment: Not, I can't find any good information about it how to get this done 0_o

Comment: Well Firefox needs to be installed. It's a requirement to have the browser you want to use installed. This is your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response again, where should I install the package? Which path?

Comment: If you keep it to the default path, Selenium should pick it up from there. If you do want to give it a particular place, look at the `firefox_binary` class: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py

Comment: thanks again! What is the particular path? /usr/bin ? I work from command line.. :$

Answer (score 3):

You can use iceweasel instead of the 'proper' release of firefox.

```
apt-get install iceweasel

python
>>> import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: Yes but the rendering of a website is not always GREAT with iceweasel :x

Comment: Well then you'll have to install Firefox: http://superuser.com/questions/322376/how-to-install-real-firefox-on-debian

Comment: It raise an error:raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "